# Что изучать перед изучением Razor c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

Решил начать изучать веб-программирование и так как изучал c# выбор пал на asp.net Razor. Что мне нужно знать перед освоением Razor? html знаю, но всё ровно не понимаю что написано даже в index.cshtml, который генерируется изначально.

Comment: Скачайте любую книжку по asp.net и почитайте. Какие проблемы с этим?

Answer (score 3):

Нужно знать только основы HTML и основы C#. Сам Razor не сложная вещь, нужно потренироваться с `@`, как она работает с циклами, using, как писать C#-код внутри HTML-кода, который внутри другого C#-кода, т.е. большим уровнем вложенности. Для себя сделал такую **шпаргалку**, может вам пригодится.

```
Схема           | x

@*x*@           | комментарий
@x              | переменная / метод / @ (выведется "@")
@(x)            | переменная / метод / литерал / выражение
@{x}            | C#-код (инструкции), HTML-код (как инструкции)
<text>x</text>  | HTML-код
```

**Особенности веб-страницы CSHTML**

1. Языком по умолчанию CSHTML-страницы является HTML.
2. Блок C#-кода располагается внутри HTML-кода.
3. Блоки C#-кода имеют общую область видимости.
4. Внутри @{} языком по умолчанию является C#.
5. Внутри @{} HTML-код выполняется как инструкция C#.
6. Блок < text ></ text > располагается внутри C#-кода.
7. Внутри < text >< /text > языком по умолчанию является HTML.
8. В строковом литерале символы HTML не интерпретируются.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

CSHTML примера

```
<div class="container-fluid tbl">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col"><b>CSHTML</b></div>
        <div class="col"><b>Браузер</b></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">@@@@</div>
        <div class="col">@@</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <mark>@@</mark>
            DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()
        </div>
        <div class="col">@DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <mark>@@(</mark>
            1 + 2
            <mark>)</mark>
        </div>
        <div class="col">@(1 + 2)</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <mark>@@(</mark>
            @("<h1>Hello World!</h1>")
            <mark>)</mark>
        </div>
        <div class="col">@("<h1>Hello World!</h1>")</div>
    </div>
    @*
        Комментарий
    *@
    @{
        string s = "<h1>Hello World!";
    }
    @{
        s += "</h1>";
    }
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div>
                <mark>@@*</mark>
                Комментарий
                <mark>*@@</mark>
            </div>
            <div>
                <mark>@@{</mark>
                @(" string s = \"<h1>Hello World!\"; ")
                <mark>}@@</mark>
            </div>
            <div>
                <mark>@@{</mark>
                @(" s += \"</h1>\"; ")
                <mark>}@@</mark>
            </div>
            <div>
                <mark>@@</mark>s
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">@s</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <mark>@@</mark>for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)<br />
            {<br />
            @("<div>")<mark>@@</mark>@("i</div>")<br />
            <mark>@("<text>")</mark>i<mark>@("</text>")</mark><br />
            }
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            @for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                <div>@i</div>
                <text>i</text>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<style>
    .tbl .col {
        max-width: 300px;
    }
    .tbl .row:not(:first-child) .col:first-child {
        font-family: Consolas;
    }
</style>
```